# How to use timerange in Maya for a single frame?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I am trying to write a python script on Maya and I want to bake only one single frame.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.bakeResults( obj, time=(1,1) ) # want to bake only frame 1
```

There is an error like this

```
Error: RuntimeError: Both start time AND end time need to be specified #
```

Tried these

```
time=(1,)
time=1
time="1"
time=("1","1")
```

Still doesn't work. Also, in the [Maya bakeResults documentation](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/bakeResults.html), it said that **See the code examples below on how to format for a single frame or frame ranges.** But no code example that includes single frame.

Comment: Just chiming in to confirm your findings. I have had no luck working around this limitation. Passing the time as a tuple works as expected if the range is greater than 1. I guess you could try something like `cmds.bakeResults(obj, time=(1,2), sampleBy=2)` and see if that skips the second frame.

Answer (score 1):

You could bake over a range of 1 and delete the 2nd key that's baked down if you absolutely needed to get rid of the second key.  That time flag won't accept anything but a tuple, so you need to provide at least two values, a start and end time that don't equal to each other.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
obj = cmds.ls(sl=True)
cmds.bakeResults(obj, time = (1,2))
cmds.cutKey(obj, time = (2,3), clear = True)
```